# Is there a way to update a nested object in MongoDB using Mongoose and TypeScript without replacing it completely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to append a new property to existing object in the mongodb document.

This is the document structure

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('XXX'),
  tenant_id: '',
  ck_details: {
    leadId: '',
    refNum: ''
  }
}
```

Now I want to insert the `appId` property inside `ck_details` Object. `ck_details` is object not an array so I don't want to push like array.

I already tried with `$set` with `updateOne()` but it completely update the `ck_details` Object.

```
TenantModel.updateOne({ tenant_id: 'tenantId' }, { $set: { ck_details: { appId } } })
```

I also tried with `$push` but as docs suggest it will push as array in the object.

```
TenantModel.updateOne({ tenant_id: 'tenantId' }, { $set: { ck_details: { $push: { appId } } } })
```

I also tried enabling `$upsert` flag but it didn't work out too.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9oPisH-rzff? try with `"cardknox_details.appId": appId `

Comment: btw what is appId variable, is it a string or something

Comment: yes, it's a variable, type of integer variable.

Comment: cool. you can add an asnwer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Set Fields in Embedded Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) doc:

> To specify a `<field>` in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

[Embedded Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/document/#embedded-documents)

> To specify or access a field of an embedded document with dot notation, concatenate the embedded document name with the dot (.) and the field name, and enclose in quotes

It should be :

```js
TenantModel.updateOne(
  { tenant_id: 'tenantId' }, 
  { $set: { 'ck_details.appId': appId } }
)
```